# How to access properties of angular material components?

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, angular5

I'm fairly new to angular in general, i have built my first few apps with it and right now I'm working on some project that contains angular material.

When i go to [this](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api) site i see lots of properties of the MatSelect directive. There is one property called 'empty: boolean' that I would like to access in some way, but i don't know how, can you help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pay attention to `Exported as:matSelect`. You can reference it by template reference variable(#var) or by ViewChild:

```
  <mat-select #matSelect = 'matSelect'>
  ...
```

**component.ts:**

```
   @ViewChild('matSelect') child: MatSelect; 
   //or
   @ViewChild(MatSelect) child: MatSelect;
```

https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelect

[Demo Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-select-scroll-problem-m46xxt)

Comment: `#matSelect = 'matSelect'` can be replaced with `#matSelect`

Comment: @trichetriche, yes, thanks, like: `<mat-select #matSelect>` It's more clear way

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `@ViewChild` decorator. Query for the `MatSelect` component imported from `@angular/material`. Keep in mind that elements queried by the `@ViewChild` decorator are available after the view is init (hence the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook).

**select.overview.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{ food.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**select.overview.ts**

```
import {Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MatSelect} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css'],
})
export class SelectOverviewExample implements AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChild(MatSelect) select: MatSelect;

  foods = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.select.empty)
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bwtyfn)