# How to close mat-select when user clicks on the mat-form-field

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using mat-select in my angular project as a dropdown language selector.

I expect the mat-select to close when I click on the mat-form-field (shown in the image with a red oval) but it doesn't.

[image: mat-select dropdown]

Kindly note that I studied the [official docs](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api) and found out mat-select has a method called `close` which

> Closes the overlay panel and focuses the host element.

I figured if I could call this method whenever the panel is open and user clicks on the panel, my issue will be fixed. I just don't know how to use this method and couldn't find anything in the docs.

This is my `html`:

```
<mat-form-field class="locale-selector">
        <mat-select
          disableOptionCentering
          [value]="currentLocaleModel.locale"
          panelClass="locale-selector-panel"
          (valueChange)="handleLocaleChange($event)"
        >
          <mat-option
            *ngFor="let item of availableLocales"
            [value]="item.locale"
          >
            {{ item.caption }}
          </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a ViewChild to be able to use it in the ts code.

The angular explanation:

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

And someone using it on a MatSelect:

[How to access properties of angular material components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49793554/how-to-access-properties-of-angular-material-components)

Answer (score 1):

you can use hash tag(#) and use element directly in html.

```
<mat-form-field click="mySelect.close()" class="locale-selector">
        <mat-select #mySelect
          disableOptionCentering
          [value]="currentLocaleModel.locale"
          panelClass="locale-selector-panel"
          (valueChange)="handleLocaleChange($event)"
        >
          <mat-option
            *ngFor="let item of availableLocales"
            [value]="item.locale"
          >
            {{ item.caption }}
          </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

The MatSelectPanel should close when clicked anywhere outside the panel by default. There should be no need to use any other functionality.
You can see this in this [Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzm92t?file=src/app/select-form-example.html).

Else please provide a fiddle/blitz of your problem for a better understanding